# How to get Web Bluetooth to send multiple `characteristicvaluechanged` events?

Tags: web-bluetooth

[paraphrasing an IRC conversation]

Trying to build a temperature sensor with ardunio and a DHT11 sensor and a HM10 bluetooth sensor. When getting the temperature values with Web Bluetooth but it doesn't seem to be firing the `characteristicvaluechanged` event. It only gives the initial value.

```js
document.querySelector('button')
    .addEventListener('click', connectBluetooth)


function connectBluetooth() {
    navigator.bluetooth
        .requestDevice({
            optionalServices: [ 0xffe0 ],
            acceptAllDevices: true
        })
        .then(device => device.gatt.connect())
        .then(server => server.getPrimaryService(0xffe0))
        .then(service => service.getCharacteristic(0xffe1))
        .then(characteristic => {
            characteristic.addEventListener('characteristicvaluechanged',
                                            handleValueChanged)

            return characteristic.readValue()
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
}

function handleValueChanged(event) {
    console.log('Handling...')
    let value = event.target.value.getUint8(0)

    console.log(`The value is: ${value}`)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never subscribed to notifications. See https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/notifications.html for an example. Registering the event listener is not sufficient, you must also call `characteristic.startNotifications()`. The `readValue` was returning one result, so just replace it with `startNotifications`.